# ImageView inside Grid Item blocks long click

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a gridview that some items has ImageViews that fills parent view. When I set onItemLongClickListener, it works fine with the one that has no image view, but the ones with the image views seem to block the event. I tried to set the image views disabled, and tried to set their onclick listeners to null, even tried to set focusable to false, but nothing worked the way i need it to.

I've put no codes because my codes are too long. I just need to know how to make the whole item clickable without the imageview inside it interfering. Thank you so much.

Here's the code snippet of on item long click:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView gridView, View view, int position, long row) {
    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

Here's the grid item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cellLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="94dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/planner_date_mon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="-5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/planner_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/planner_date_day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/planner_meal_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/howto"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/planner_meal_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/planner_meal_image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/planner_meal_type"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/planner_meal_image"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/green" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just paste the code, which contains only click event.

Comment: it just contains a toast. but, sure.

Comment: Have you implemented click event on ImageView as well?

Comment: yes, inside the adapter's getView. that's where  I also tried to set the imageView enabled, and focusable.

Comment: Ya so that is the problem, your adapter view is finding click event of ImageView I think.

Comment: yes yes, the click event of imageview is blocking the click event of the grid item. please help me to fix this.

Comment: I think you have to do it some other way because you will not get these both click events. You must declare any layout to display row. then, put one click event on image and second long click event on your whole layout, not on listview row, but on LAYOUT of your row. I think that will work.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it. Yes, they can't fire simultaneously. That's why I set the imageview clickable to false and enabled to false. but the item long click still won't fire.

Comment: Dont implement Item click event, instead use your layout click event. Please paste your layout file here.

Comment: i didn't, only the onItemLongClick. are those the same?
which layout file, the one with the gridview or the grid item's layout?

Comment: Yes exactly, paste here.

Comment: There you go. Sorry i'm new in android development.

Comment: cellLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

Comment: Lei, its okay, I will help you if you have any doubt, can we share our emails?

Comment: Sure, mine is ljcleyba@gmail.com